# Mapping Class Column Headers in Python SQLAlchemy from CSV import

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, sqlalchemy

I set up the column names in the class like below:

```
class Stat1(Base):
__tablename__ = 'stat1'
__table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}

id = Column(VARCHAR, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
Date_and_Time = Column(VARCHAR)
IP_Address = Column(VARCHAR)
Visitor_Label = Column(VARCHAR)
Browser = Column(VARCHAR)
Version = Column(VARCHAR)
```

The csv file does not use the UNDERSCORE in the column names. It is a csv file downloaded from the internet. For instance, when I import the column names headers like "Date_and_Time" are imported as "Date and Time".

I had assumed (that's wrong, right?) that the CSV's column name would map to the class column headers I set up but that's not happening and the queries are not running properly because of it. I am getting messages like this:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such
>   column: stat1.Date_and_Time [SQL: 'SELECT stat1.id AS stat1_id,
>   stat1."Date_and_Time" AS "stat1_Date_and_Time", stat1."IP_Address" AS
>   "stat1_IP_Address"...etc.

Is there a way to map these automatically so that queries are successful? Or a way to change the CSV's column headings automatically to insert an UNDERSCORE in the column headings to match with the columns defined in the Class?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different ways that you can approach this:

**Implement Your Own De-serialization Logic**

This means that the process of reading your CSV file and mapping its columns to your `Base` model class' attributes is done manually (as in your question), and then you read / map your CSV using your own custom code.

I think, in this scenario, having underscores in your model class attributes (`Stat1.Date_and_Time`) but *not* in your CSV header (`...,"Date and Time",...`) will complicate your code a bit. However, depending on how you've implemented your mapping code you *can* set your `Column` to use one model attribute name (`Stat1.Date_and_Time`) 
and a *different* database column name (e.g. have `Stat1.Date_and_Time` map to your database column `"Date and Time"`). To accomplish this, you need to pass the `name` argument as below:

```
    class Stat1(Base):

        __tablename__ = 'stat1'
        __table_args__ = { 'sqlite_autoincrement': True }

        id = Column(name = 'id', type_ = VARCHAR, primary_key = True, nullable = False)
        Date_and_Time = Column(name = 'Date and Time', type_ = VARCHAR)
        IP_Address = Column(name = 'IP Address', type_ = VARCHAR)
        # etc.
```

Now when you read records from your CSV file, you will need to load them into the appropriate model attributes in your `Stat1` class. A pseudo-code example would be:

```
    id, date_and_time, ip_address = read_csv_record(csv_record)
    # Let's assume the "read_csv_record()" function reads your CSV record and returns
    # the appropriate value for `id`, `Date_And_Time`, and `IP_Address`

    my_record = Stat1(id = id,
                      Date_And_Time = date_and_time,
                      ip_address
                      # etc.)
```

Here, the trick is in implementing your `read_csv_record()` function so that it reads and returns the column values for your model attributes, so that you can then pass them appropriately to your `Stat1()` constructor.

**Use SQLAthanor**

An (I think easier) alternative to implementing your own de-serialization solution is to use a library like **[SQLAthanor](https://github.com/insightindustry/sqlathanor)** (full disclosure: I'm the library's author, so I'm a bit biased). Using SQLAthanor, you can either:

1. Create your `Stat` model class programmatically:

   ```
   from sqlathanor import generate_model_from_csv

   Stat1 = generate_model_from_csv('your_csv_file.csv',
                                   'stat1',
                                   primary_key = 'id')
   ```

   Please note, however, that if your column header names are not ANSI SQL standard column names (if they contain spaces, for example), this will likely produce an error.
2. Define your model, and then create instances from your CSV.

   To do this, you would define your model very similarly to how you do above:

   ```
   from sqlathanor import BaseModel

   class Stat1(BaseModel):

       __tablename__ = 'stat1'
       __table_args__ = { 'sqlite_autoincrement': True }

       id = Column(name = 'id', type_ = VARCHAR, primary_key = True, nullable = False, supports_csv = True, csv_sequence = 1)
       Date_and_Time = Column(name = 'Date and Time', type_ = VARCHAR, supports_csv = True, csv_sequence = 2)
       IP_Address = Column(name = 'IP Address', type_ = VARCHAR, supports_csv = True, csv_sequence = 3)
       # etc.
   ```

   The `supports_csv` argument tells your `Stat1` class that model attribute `Stat1.id` can be de-serialized from (and serialized to) CSV, and the `csv_sequence` argument indicates that it will always be the first column in a CSV record.

   Now you can create a new `Stat1` instance (a record in your database) by passing your CSV record to `Stat1.new_from_csv()`:

   ```
   # let's assume you have loaded a single CSV record into a variable "csv_record"
   my_record = Stat1.new_from_csv(csv_record)
   ```

   and that's it! Now your `my_record` variable will contain an object representation of your CSV record, which you can then commit to the database if and when you choose. Since there is a wide variety of ways that CSV files can be constructed (using different delimiters, wrapping strategies, etc.) there are a large number of configuration arguments that can be supplied to `.new_from_csv()`, but you can find all of them documented here: https://sqlathanor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#new-from-csv

   SQLAthanor is an extremely robust library for moving data into / out of CSV and SQLAlchemy, so I strongly recommend you review the documentation. Here are the important links:

   - [Github Repo](https://github.com/insightindustry/sqlathanor/)
   - [Comprehensive Documentation](https://sqlathanor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
   - [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/sqlathanor/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will definitely check out that library. From all indications, it may help with other things as well. My goal was to programmatically download the file once a day using Selenium, save it to a directory, and then CRON the scripts to upload the CSV file to populate the database. Then retrieve the data I need with calculations with queries and serve to Flask. So I am trying to avoid as much manual manipulation as possible. However, it may be that once I have everything set properly the first time then subsequent attempts may require no manipulation.